# LEGO or LEGO-compatible control for SG90 servo?

Tags: power-functions, 3rd-party

Is there a way to control **three-wire** servo (for example the [SG90 servo](https://components101.com/motors/servo-motor-basics-pinout-datasheet) or other common models) by LEGO Power Functions or CaDA power function?

Answer (score 4):

No, the electrical signal is not compatible. These hobby-type servo motors take a 50Hz signal with a pulse width that varies between 1 and 2 milliseconds.

It could be possible though using MINDSTORMS NXT or EV3 using an [IR Receiver](https://modernroboticsinc.com/product/hitechnic-nxt-irreceiver-sensor/) and a [Servo Controller](http://www.mindsensors.com/ev3-and-nxt/25-8-channel-servo-controller-for-nxt-or-ev3).